# Make custom changes in admin generator

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I develop a symfony 1.4 project,my issue with admin panel in backend,so I use the administration generator to do it.

I have a list of members generated automatically in backend,now Im hopping to add some custom action when a memeber edit her profile in backend,then I wish to add in edit page radio dial buttons give simple “Yes” or “No” Options. By default, the radial dial button is set to “No.” However, if the admin selects “Yes” then a popup window will come with the following text: “Are you sure you want to sell a new membership" and If the admin selects “Yes” and then saves the profile, a pop Window will need to display that reads: “New Membership sold"...

the problem is I can't change code because the form of edition page is generated using a plugin (sfguarduser) so It's deficult to make any changes?

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the plugin documentation](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin) says, you can override the plugin module by creating a module with the same name in the application you want and by adding a require_once in the action.

As for your confirm and other javascript, you can override the generated partials by adding partials with the same name in your module, just as described [here](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/reference/1_4/fr/06-Admin-Generator).